# Relationship between trace of a linear map and the number of points it fixes.

Tags: linear-algebra, differential-geometry, differential-topology

Problem Statement: Let $\Phi_A:T^2\rightarrow T^2$ be a smooth mapping into the torus induced by a linear map $A\in SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$ under the quotient relation that identifies 0 and 1. Assume that A does not have 1 as an eigenvalue. Show that the number of fixed points can be expressed in terms of the Trace of A only.

Thoughts: The condition that $\Phi_A$ has a fixed point is equivalent to $A$ taking a point $(a,b)\in \mathbb{R}^2$ to $(a+m,b+n)$ where $m,n\in \mathbb{Z}$. Multiplying the matrix by a vector $(a,b)$ with entries $\alpha, \beta, \gamma, \delta$ we obtain equations $(a,b)=(\alpha a + \beta b, \gamma a + \delta b)$. Those can only differ by the addition of an integer, so $\beta = \gamma = 0$ and then the only two elements of the matrix left are the eigenvalues - the terms which are found in the Trace. and if A takes something to ($\alpha a, \beta b$) then $\Phi_A$ must take it to $(a,b)$ since they differ by an integer.

I can't seem to get the equation for the # of fixed points out of this list of observations. Help appreciated, will upvote.

EDIT: Solution

If we substitute the A into its characteristic polynomial of A and use Cayley Hamilton, we get: $A^2(a,b)+tr(A)A(a,b)+1=0$ which is equivalent to $(a,b)+A(m,n)−tr(A)(a,b)−tr(A)(m,n)+(a,b)=0$ which we can solve for $(a,b)$ to get... $2−tr(A)(a,b)=(A+I−tr(A))(m,n)$. This line tells us that that $2−tr(A)(a,b)∈\mathbb{Z}$, i.e, $(a,b)$ are multiples of $12−tr(A)$ generated by some $(m,n).$ Furthermore, we have $(a,b)=12−tr(A)(A+I−tr(A)(m,n).$ The linear map on the right side has $detA=2−tr(A).$

That means that the unit parallelogram of the lattice has area $2−tr(A)$ and therefore in each unit square, there will be $2−tr(A)$ copies of the unit parallelogram lying inside the unit square. The lattice points lying inside the unit square are precisely those which don't differ by some $(m,n)∈\mathbb{Z}$. Since there are $2−tr(A)$ copies in the Unit square, we'll have 2−tr(A) corner points, and those points each correspond to an equivalence class of solutions.

Comment: Something is fishy here. What if the trace of $A$ is negative?

Comment: So apparently I red the problem wrong, the number of fixed points isn't necessarily equal to trace A, but it is a function of only trace A.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try writing the equations as $A \begin{pmatrix}a \\ b \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} a \\ b \end{pmatrix} + \begin{pmatrix}m \\ n \end{pmatrix}.$ (Here $(a,b)$ is a point in $\mathbb R^2$, and $(m,n)$ is a point in $\mathbb Z^2$.)

Rewriting, this gives $(A - I)\begin{pmatrix} a \\ b \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}m \\ n \end{pmatrix}.$

Now the number of fixed points is the number of inequivalent solutions to this equation, where two solutions are regarded as equivalent if their $(a,b)$ differ by something in $\mathbb Z^2$.

You can just solve this equation by linear algebra, if you just choose some $(m,n)$, but note that while $A- I$ has integer entries, its inverse may not --- and if you compute $\det A - I$, you will see the role of the trace of $A$.  So choosing different $(m,n)$ can give non-equivalent solutions, and if you think carefully about how many equivalence classes of solutions you can get, you will find your desired formula.

---

Added at the OP's request:  First we compute that $\det( A - I ) = 2 - \mathrm{tr} A.$  By assumption this is non-zero.

Now we have the following problem: let $M$ be a $2 \times 2$ matrix with integer entries and non-zero determinant; compute the number of solutions
to $M \begin{pmatrix} a \\ b \end{pmatrix} \in \mathbb Z^2,$ where the
solutions are also counted modulo $\mathbb Z^2$.   The answer is: the number of solutions is equal to $| \det M \, |$.

One way to see this is to use the theory of elementary divisors to reduce to the case when $M$ is diagonal.   Another way, which should at least make intuitive sense, is to see that the preimage of a unit square under multiplication by $M$ will have area $| \det M \, |^{-1}$, so we will be able to find $| \det M \, |$ such preimages which don't differ by an element of $\mathbb Z^2$.

Comment: Nice, Matt. As is often the case, too much knowledge is a dangerous thing. :) And I hadn't stopped to think that $\det(A-I)=2-\text{tr}A$ when $A\in SL(2)$. But I am confused about how the linear algebra counts signed intersection numbers.

Comment: @Ted: Dear Ted, Thanks. I got confused about the signs for a bit too, but I think if you simply compute the sign of the origin as a fixed point of $A$, you find that it coincides with the sign of $1 - \operatorname{tr} A + \det A$.  One can probably also see it more geometrically: e.g. if $\operatorname{tr} A > 2$, then $A$ has two positive real eigenvalues, $\lambda > 1$ and $1/\lambda < 1$, and so at a fixed point we have one incoming direction (the $1/\lambda$ eigenaxis) and one outgoing direction (the $\lambda$ eigenaxis), and so the fixed point has sign $-1$.    Cheers,

Comment: I was wondering, would it be possible for you to post the solution in full? I solved this several months ago, but I'm reviewing now and I can't find the problem set and can't seem to regenerate the solution, meaning I obviously didn't really understand it the first time. Where do the equivalence classes come from?

Comment: I'm actually quite confused. I don't understand why taking the determinant yields information about the fixed points, unless it's like, the number of lattice points the spanned parallelepiped (which I see would be fixed) because of det 1. Trace is the semiperimeter of that shape, and depending on the value of the eigenvalues, a certain number of lattice points will lie in its volume. If we make copies of this region we could cover the with equivalence classes... but I can't get from there to why this formula gives us the correct number.

Comment: @user42693: Dear user, I added something; hopefully it helps.  Did you actually try to solve the equation relating $(a,b)$ and $(m,n)$, and think about how many different $(a,b)$'s you can get for a given $(m,n)$ that are mutually non-congruent mod $\mathbb Z^2$?  If you try doing this, say for some fixed choice of $A -I$ in elementary divisor form, maybe $\begin{pmatrix} 2 & 0 \\ 0 & 6\end{pmatrix}$, you should see how it works out.  Regards,

Comment: Ok I think I got something. So if we substitute the A into its characteristic polynomial of A and use Cayley Hamilton, we get:

$A^2(a,b)+tr(A)A(a,b)+1=0$ which is equivalent to
$(a,b)+A(m,n)-tr(A)(a,b)-tr(A)(m,n)+(a,b)=0$ which we can solve for (a,b) to get...
$2-tr(A)(a,b)=(A+I-tr(A))(m,n).$ This line tells us that that $2-tr(A)(a,b)\in\mathbb{Z}$, i.e, $(a,b)$ are multiples of $\frac{1}{2-tr(A)}$ generated by some $(m,n)$. Furthermore, we have $(a,b)=\frac{1}{2-tr(A)}(A+I-tr(A)(m,n)$. The linear map on the right side has $det A=2-tr(A).$

Comment: That means that the unit parallelogram of the lattice has area $2-tr(A)$ and therefore in each unit square, there will be $2-tr(A)$ copies of the unit parallelogram lying inside the unit square. The lattice points lying inside the unit square are precisely those which don't differ by some $(m,n)\in\mathbb{Z}$. Since there are $2-tr(A)$ copies in the Unit square, we'll have $2-tr(A)$ corner points, and those points each correspond to an equivalence class of solutions.

I haven't taken Galois theory yet so I don't know much about elementary divisors . Do you have any reading recommendations?

Comment: @user: Dear user, You can do worse than the [wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith_normal_form); just take the PID $A$ in that discussion to be $\mathbb Z$, and $m = n = 2$.  Think of the invertible matrices in the discussion as changing coordinates in $(a,b)$ and $(m,n)$ independently (but both coord. changes are given by invertible matrices over $\mathbb Z$, so they don't do any damage to the property of being an integral solution!).  You can then assume that $A$ is in Smith normal form, which makes solving the equation for $(a,b)$ particularly easy.  Regards,

Answer (score 3):

Yes, interpreting correctly, the Lefschetz number $\lambda_f$ of the map counts the fixed points. This is — in the differential topology world — the intersection number of the diagonal in $X\times X$ with the graph of $f$. This can be computed in terms of the algebraic topology: 
$$\lambda_f = \sum (-1)^k \text{tr}\big(f_*\colon H_k(X) \to H_k(X)\big).$$
In the case of your problem, this is going to be $2-\text{tr}A$.

Comment: This seems to evoke a rather strong result I'm not totally familiar with. I understand the intersection with the diagonal would count fixed  points, but what is $H_k(X)?$ I think perhaps in this problem, we were supposed to arrive at that through more elementary methods.

Comment: Dear Ted, Perhaps I am getting confused about the signs, but won't it be $2 - \mathrm{tr}A$?  Regards,

Comment: @user42693: it's very difficult to guess what background people have. The fact that $1$ is not an eigenvalue should tell us that the graph is in fact transverse to the diagonal, so we do just need to count intersection points with signs. Can you see why we should get $2$ when the trace is $0$, e.g., $\left[\begin{array} {cc}0&-1\\1&0\end{array}\right]$? I have never tried to do this without the algebraic topology.